# Постоянное получение данных SQL таблицы с помощью программы на python используя pymysql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

Нужно постоянно получать обновленные данные из SQL таблицы с помощью модуля `pymysql`. Написал такую программу:

```
import pymysql
import sys

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        user = "user",
        password = "UpbLTHjpnp[Pr2X6", 
        database = "new",
        cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
except:
    sys.exit()

def parse_db(db_name):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{db_name}`;")
        return cursor.fetchall()

def get_tasks():
    while True:
        tasks = parse_db("tasks")
        headers = []

        for i in range(len(tasks)):
            headers.append(tasks[i]["header"])

        print(headers)


get_tasks()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если во время работы программы добавить в SQL таблицу новые данные, программа их показывать не будет, то есть для просмотра обновленных данных мне нужно перезапустить программу. Как это сделать без перезапуска?

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто обновлять соединение в функции `parse_db()`

```
import pymysql
import sys

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        user = "user",
        password = "UpbLTHjpnp[Pr2X6", #root - root
        database = "new",
        cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
except:
    sys.exit()

def parse_db(db_name):

    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(
            host = "127.0.0.1",
            user = "user",
            password = "UpbLTHjpnp[Pr2X6", #root - root
            database = "new",
            cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
    except:
        sys.exit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{db_name}`;")
        return cursor.fetchall()

def get_tasks():
    while True:
        tasks = parse_db("tasks")
        headers = []

        for i in range(len(tasks)):
            headers.append(tasks[i]["header"])

        print(headers)


get_tasks()
```